# Can a hacked Twitter be used to access a person's email?

Tags: twitter, authentication, hacked

Sorry if I sound overly paranoid, but I was hacked earlier today on Twitter and I was wondering if the person who did it would be able to access my email?

Comment: I'm not sure the "hacked" tag is a good one for us to have in general, because it doesn't really pertain to a specific application's functionality, but it fits this situation, so I will leave it for now.

Answer (score 2):

No, as per my knowledge no one can access email from twitter details, even you will not be able to access your email without knowing password of that particular email id.